# Pass data from html file into registered vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a vue app setup like so:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import RecommendedJobsWidget from './RecommendedJobsWidget.vue'

createApp(RecommendedJobsWidget).mount("#recommendedJobsWidgetInstance");
```

My HTML is like so:

```
<body>
  <div id="recommendedJobsWidgetInstance">
    <recommended-jobs-widget :message="'messagehere'"></recommended-jobs-widget>
  </div>
<script src="/ui/migrate/dist/recommended_jobs_widget.js"></script>
</body>
```

My app is loading as I expect but inside the component `<recommended-jobs-widget>` I am trying to send a `message` prop. Inside my component I am accepting the prop:

```
props: ['message']
```

but when I try to access the prop inside my component it doesn't exist. I have tried various solutions and none of my data is ever being passed as a prop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Do you want to set the message as `:message="'messagehere'"`? You can remove the single quotes, it is already a string. 2) Can you see your component in Vue Dev Tools? 3) Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: No errors and I have tried without the single quotes.

Comment: Ah ok it needs to be without `:` as well for just a string value. You need `:` for dynamic values (like a function returning something). Otherwise, can we see how you access the prop in the component?

Answer (score 2):

As was previously mentioned by @AfterDark017 Vue3 does something to the element that makes the data unavailable to itself via `defineProps` or `useAttr`.  However, the object is available on for the `main.ts` script at least it should be there otherwise it won't have any place to mount to.

So what you can do for example in *index.html*

```
<body>
  <div id="app" data-recaptcha-site-key="_NOT_REALLY_">
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
</body>
```

In `main.ts`

```
const recaptchaSiteKey = document
  .getElementById("app")!
  .getAttribute("data-recaptcha-site-key") as string;

createApp(App)
  .provide(RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY, recaptchaSiteKey)
  .mount("#app");
```

Then access the data using `inject` e.g.

```
import { inject } from 'vue';
const recapchaSiteKey = inject(RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);
```

Comment: Helpful solution! I would suggest changing the provide/inject keys to strings to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way of passing data via props to root components in VueJS 3.

The root component renders automatically inside the mounted `<div>` container (and strips out anything that's inside it), so you'll find that just writing the following will still render your root component (unless your root component doesn't have a `<template>`):

```html
<body>
  <div id="recommendedJobsWidgetInstance"></div>
  <script src="/ui/migrate/dist/recommended_jobs_widget.js"></script>
</body>
```

I need the exact same thing (passing data into Vue components), and the closest one I've come across (after hours of googling and reading documentations) is this: [Pass data from html file into registered vue app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222580/pass-data-from-html-file-into-registered-vue-app)

> You could not access that using props, but you could get the value of that attribute using some Vanilla js DOM like document.getElementById("app").getAttribute("someVariable")

**This would mean for your case**:

```html
<body>
  <div id="recommendedJobsWidgetInstance" message="messagehere"></div>
  <script src="/ui/migrate/dist/recommended_jobs_widget.js"></script>
</body>
```

And then, inside your `RecommendedJobWidget.vue` component:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- your HTML -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RecommendedJobWidget",
  data() {
    return {
      message: ""
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.message = document.getElementById("recommendedJobsWidgetInstance").getAttribute("message");
  }
}
</script>
```

If there's a better way I'd love to know it, as I am not very happy how Vue3 seems to be meant for SPAs only.

Comment: I want to use the HTML spec of `data-my-variable="123"` on the outer element, but Vue 3 creates its instances _within_ that outer element, thus has no association with it (right??). You can, however, grab that value via `document.querySelector("#the-outer-el").dataset.myVariable` but that demands that the user of your component knows that the outer non-Vue element requires that data attribute. Therefore, I slap it on the `window` object. Keep that data to an ID, etc. that is then used to call an API.

Comment: We also use `window` to pass data between html and Vue; imho it's preferably to making placeholder elements to hold data.

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking in a way that can send data but with semantic safeness and I’m thinking in meta tags if you have the data in the html render you can convert this data in meta tags instead of passing as props and when you make it you can get it in the vue app that loads after the head and paint the component based on head allowing you to use a dynamic component strategy to load the component in the main app I will test it and share my code soon